# rust: use of undeclared type name `io::IOResult`

Tags: rust

In rust I have the following

```
use std::io;
fn lookup(host: &str, timeout_duration: time::Duration) -> io::IOResult<Vec<ip::IpAddr>>{
    // Some blah implementation here...
}
```

However I'm getting a compilation error.

```
src/hello.rs:7:60: 7:89 error: use of undeclared type name `io::IOResult`
```

I'm confused because there is clearly an IOResult struct in the std::io namespace (as of November 16 2014): http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.IoResult.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't capitalize the name (doh): `IOResult` -> `IoResult`

The signature is

```
type IoResult<T> = Result<T, IoError>;
```